# Copy Every Nth Row with Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel VBA to create a macro to copy every other row starting at P7 downward. I want these copied values to be pasted normally into another workbook as a continuous column. I am pretty sure this will require a for loop, but I am not sure how to do it in VBA. Below is my current code, which just copies the filled rows without skipping.

```
Option Explicit
Sub copyRange()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wkbDest As Workbook
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Dim strExtension As String
    Dim LastRowC As Long
    Dim LastRowP As Long
    Dim filterRange As Range
    Dim copyRange As Range

    Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\UPLOADS2\"
    ChDir strPath
    strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")
    Do While strExtension <> ""
        Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
        With wkbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")
            LastRowC = wkbSource.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            'LastRowP = wkbDest.Worksheets("WIP").Cells(wkbDest.Worksheets("WIP").Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            wkbSource.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4:B" & LastRowC).Copy
            wkbDest.Worksheets("WIP").Range("P7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
        wkbSource.Close savechanges:=False
        strExtension = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a loop for this?  "I don't know how" would lead one to say "loop it up."  To help narrow your search, try a `For` loop, e.g., `for i = 4 to LastRowC Step 2` meaning that every `next i` the loop will iterate 2 steps.

Comment: Oh okay, I did not know of the Step keyword. Thank you

Comment: Or loop `i` normally and use `2*i` (or `2*i+1`) for the rows you copy and `i` for the rows you paste to

Comment: If that resolves your issue, I can post as an answer so we can get the question flagged as *Answered*... keeps things from lingering indefinitely.

Comment: I believe it does, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage the `step` of a `for` loop to modify the number iterated via `next i`, such that:

```
Dim i as Long
For i = 4 to LastRowC Step 2
    'Use Cells(i,"B") or Range("B" & i)
Next i
```

In this case, the step of 2 would make you go from 4 to 6 to 8, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, an alternative without any loop:

```
Dim lr As Long

With Sheet1
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row: If lr Mod 2 = 1 Then lr = lr - 1
    .Range(Join(.Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(""B""&2+ROW(1:" & ((lr - 4) / 2) + 1 & ")*2)"), ",")).Copy
End With
```

Not tested, but might speed up the process since you only need to use the clipboard once.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a complete subroutine that will select every 2nd cell in a selected range and then copy the cells to the clipboard. This will work on a range of rows in a single column.  It shouldn't be too difficult to modify it to make it work in the other direction, though.  If you want to copy every 3rd, 4th, etc. cell you just need to modify the `Step` value in the for loop.

```
Sub Select_Every_Other()
'
' Select_Every_Other Macro
' Select every other cell in a selected range (column)
'
    Dim Rng As Range        ' original selection
    Dim myCell As Range     ' temp variable
    Dim myUnion As Range    ' final selection
    Set Rng = Selection

    For i = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count Step 2
        Set myCell = Rng.Cells(i)
        If myUnion Is Nothing Then                  ' if myUnion is empty (first time through loop)
            Set myUnion = myCell                    ' create a new union
        Else                                        ' if myUnion is not empty
            Set myUnion = Union(myUnion, myCell)    ' add to the union
        End If
    Next i

    myUnion.Select
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

This code was adapted from here: https://spreadsheetplanet.com/select-every-other-cell-in-excel/